# Start Worfklow as a user with Read Only Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I'm attempting to develop a workflow that will edit a list item. I need the workflow to be able to be initiated by users with read-only permissions.

To achieve this I've attempted to include the edit portion of the workflow as an impersonation step (2010 workflow)

As of now the users receive a "This site has not been shared with you" error.

Please see my workflow steps below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When we use workflow with "impersonation step", the workflow will be running under the account of "workflow creator" instead of the user trigger the workflow.

To initial a workflow, the user need edit permission at least. I recommend you give the user edit permission.